# Should we start seasonal crop recommendation CW posts?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Fall is coming and we are wondering if a set of seasonal crop recommendation posts would be useful to the community at large.

These would be a limited set of crop recommendations by season that would be a repository of information on what to grow for each of the season complete with estimated time to harvest from either seed or seedling and also what temperatures the plant can tolerate.

I am looking for ideas on how these posts should be constructed and whether or not they will be useful to the community at large.

Comment: This sounds like something better suited to, say, a blog post.

Answer (score 4):

As proposed, this would be far too localized to be useful to a wide audience.

In NH, I see snow flurries in late September / early October and expect 2-4" of snowfall in November. About all I can count on for unprotected fall/winter crops are spinach, kale, and carrots. In GA your frosts are later and you'd have a much wider choice. In the US Northwest, I think fall/winter is the rainy season, so that's going to present it's own set of challenges.

Same thing for midsummer: I can grow lettuce here with some care, but it's harder in TX.

However, it is possible to give good answers to questions about specific environments:

> What are good fall crops to plant in August for harvest by late November for my cold-weather garden? We will see hard frost (20-28F) by the time harvest arrives. The ground freezes completely by mid December.

Answers to this question would be useful to a large group of cold-climate gardeners. You could pose similar questions for milder climates or other growing challenges (wet weather).

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't this be rather a monster list? Especially as on an expert forum gardeners will expect to see specific varieties offered:

e.g.

## Lettuce

- Winter Density
- Valdor
- etc